# Verify data against certificate

Tags: java, python, certificate, ssl-certificate

```
  cert.public_key.verify(
    OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new,
    Base64.strict_decode64(signature),
    signature_data
  )
```

I am java developer, may i have java compatible code for above python script?
I have X509Certificate, when i try below code, i am getting invalid length issues. wanted verify if the code is correct? in the below code, key is X509Certificate object getKey()

```
           Signature verifySignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA"); 
            verifySignature.initVerify(key);
            verifySignature.update(signatureData.getBytes());
            boolean verified = verifySignature.verify(signatureData.getBytes());
```

Update :
The problem was i passed signatureData instead of signature to verify method. solved now

Comment: Is Python's SHA256 really the same as Java's SHA256withRSA?

Comment: Not Sure Marquis